# ¿Es posible transformar una base de datos Sqllite a Room?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment, android-sqlite

Soy novato con la programación en Android (uso Java) y me han surgido unas cuantas dudas. Es mi primer proyecto. Espero que me iluminéis un poco, por favor:

**1)** Quiero almacenar la carta de un restaurante, y luego recorrer con un for (imagen, descripción, precio ...) para que aparezca en un fragment al estilo Google Play con scrollviews en horizontal, para cada una de las categorías (Carne, Pescado, Entrantes ...).

El problema es que para eso tengo que tener una base de datos SqlLite creada de antemano y guardada en assets. Pero me pregunto, ¿es posible luego utilizar Room, porque creo que con un ORM luego se simplificarían las cosas?. La cosa es que los productos tienen que estar ya en la aplicación, no cargarlos uno a uno.

**2)** Una vez que tengo la lista con cada uno de los platos, para enviarlos al layout y que se vayan pintando en pantalla, tengo que pasar al LiveData al xml. ¿Cómo haría para crear cada uno de las vistas? Sería sólo poner la foto en pequeño y el precio, una vez que se hace click, entrar a otro fragment y me ofrezca toda la info del plato, pasando el id como parámetro.

Muchas gracias a tod@s.

Saludos.

Comment: ROOM segun internet es un ORM que va sobre sqlite (o sea, te ayuda a conectarte a sqlite).. cual seria la duda aca? y de paso, trata de hacer una pregunta por pregunta, y de especificar claramente tu problema...

Comment: Muchas gracias. Perdona, tienes razón. Saludos.

Comment: Room es una capa de abstracción, no una base de datos, está claramente explicado en la documentación de Android.

Comment: nada por que disculparse!!! trato de ayudarte a que obtengas una respuesta a tu pregunta.. si es que hay pregunta...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voy a intentar darte unas ideas de cómo lo haría para simplificar lo que quieres y no complicarte:

1. Quieres guardar la carta de un restaurante en una base de datos.  SQLite es la base de datos de Android y Room, como te han indicado, es una capa de abstracción para manejar esa base de datos.  A través de un sistema de etiquetas te permite evitar mucho boilerplate a la hora de crear tablas y consultas.

Si vas a hacer una aplicación profesional y es necesario añadir elementos a la carta desde la interfaz de usuario y modificar precios, artículos, etc. entonces usar una base de datos es una buena idea (es este caso, parece que no hay relaciones, por lo que Realm sería otra opción).

Si la aplicación no requiere modificación alguna sobre los elementos, es decir, se crea la carta sin posibilidad de hacer cambios, entonces no hace falta crear una base de datos.

2. Al ser un proyecto básico puedes usar la arquitectura que sigue Google: UI + ViewModel + Repositorio.  La ui observa el LiveData en el ViewModel y la comunicación entre VM y Repositorio la haría con corrutinas, que te permiten realizar acciones en background de una manera súper sencilla.  Mientras se están pidiendo los datos, puedes mostrar un loading en la pantalla principal(observando un LiveData por ejemplo isLoadingLiveData que recibe un Boolean), cuando recibes los datos, el isLoadingLiveData se actualiza a false y otro LiveData con la lista de la carta.

Necesitas investigar sobre RecyclerView y al principio prueba un único diseño de la celda, cuando todo funcione, ya puedes investigar para cambiar el diseño.

Al pulsar en un menú, quieres mostrar un detalle.  Este detalle puede ser una activity o un fragment, depende como estés estructurando el proyecto.  Igualmente para evitar pasar el detalle del item por Bundle, puedes compartir el ViewModel.  El ViewModel puede tener un método showDetail(detail: YourDetail) y actualizar dos livedata: el que permite la navegación notificando al fragment/activity padre que navegue y también el detailLiveData que es observado por el DetailFragment/Activity.  Puedes mostrar la imagen del menú en la lista principal y, al pulsar el detalle, esa misma imagen más grande centrada, con la animación Shared Element, es fácil de implementar y seguro que el resultado te gusta.

Comment: Muchas gracias Manuel. Seguiré tus recomendaciones, te lo agradezco mucho. Necesitaba aclararme un poco, y lo has hecho. No estaba muy seguro por donde tirar.